# How to find the current position of an image. (Sprite Kit)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am creating a game where you need to catch images moving across the screen using another image that you can move up and down the screen. Once you catch or contact one of the moving images that image is supposed to disappear and another image is supposed to spawn on top of the position of the catcher image. All of this works fine except for the fact that when the new image spawns it dose not spawn in the CURRENT position of the catcher image but in the catcher positions starting point. So how can I find the current position of the catcher image and tell the new image to spawn there. Thanks

Comment: You're going to have to share the code showing how you define the start points of the various sprites for someone to be able to answer this question for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your image is an `SKSpriteNode`...

```
let whereTheImageIs = image.position
```

Comment: Thanks. I kind of already had that but you made me realize I had that in the wrong place. It was in the did move to view. This meant that I was finding the start location that was declared in the did move to view. So I put that in the spawn the new image function and it worked. Thanks again.

Comment: @james no problem!